# Переделать из stl в rtl

Tags: c++, stl, rtl

Всем доброго дня, необходимо было написать программу разрезания многоугольника прямой, дело сделано. Правда использовал библиотеку шаблонов stl, а это оказывается недопустимо в данном задании, как максимально просто перевести это дело на rtl(runtime library)? Затруднения возникли в одной функции

RTL - значит, что нельзя использовать :

- исключения (throw, catch, try)
- приведение типов RTTI (*cast)
- Стандартная библиотека шаблонов (STL)

Код прикладываю:

```
// разрезание выпуклого многоугольника по прямой
//        функция возвращает два многоугольника
//        первый многоугольник лежит с положительной стороны от прямой
//        второй - с отрицательной
void cut_convex_for_line(vector < point > p, line l, vector < point > &v1, vector < point > &v2, point &p1, point &p2)
{
    int n = p.size();
    int i, j;

    // находим точки пересечение прямой с многоугольником и вставляем их в многоугольник
    int c = 0; // счётчик пересечений многоугольника с прямой
    list < point > s(p.begin(), p.end()); // представляем многоугольник как список вершин
    list < point > ::iterator it, jt; // итераторы обходы
    list < point > ::iterator i1, i2; // итераторы вставленных точек

    for (it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        jt = it;
        ++jt;
        if (jt == s.end()) jt = s.begin();

        // пересекаем прямую со стороной
        point t;
        int flag = cross_segment_line(*it, *jt, l, t);
        // если прямая проходит по стороне
        if (flag == 2)
        {
            if (polygon_for_line(p, l) > 0)    v1 = p;
            else    v2 = p;
            return;
        }
        // если прямая и сторона не пересекаются
        if (flag == 0) continue;

        // если прямая проходит через вершину многоугольника
        if (abs(t.x - (*it).x) <= eps && abs(t.y - (*it).y) <= eps)
        {
            if (c == 0) i1 = it;
            else i2 = it;
            ++c;
            continue;
        }
        if (abs(t.x - (*jt).x) <= eps && abs(t.y - (*jt).y) <= eps) continue;

        // иначе прямая пересекает сторону, вставляем точку пересечения в многоугольник
        ++it;
        it = s.insert(it, t);

        // увеличиваем счётчик пересечений многоугольника с прямой
        if (c == 0) i1 = it;
        else i2 = it;
        ++c;
    }

    // если прямая не пересекает многоугольник
    if (c != 2)
    {
        if (polygon_for_line(p, l) > 0)    v1 = p;
        else    v2 = p;
        return;
    }

    // представляем многоугольник массивом точек
    n = s.size();
    vector < point > all(s.begin(), s.end());
    int j1, j2;
    for (it = s.begin(), i = 0; it != s.end(); ++i, ++it)
    {
        if (it == i1) j1 = i;
        if (it == i2) j2 = i;
    }

    // режем многоугольник
    p1 = all[j1];
    p2 = all[j2];
    cut_polygon_for_edge(all, j1, j2, v1, v2);

    // если многоугольники имеют не то расположение которое нам требуется - меняем их местами
    if (polygon_for_line(v1, l) < 0)
        swap(v1, v2);
}
```

P.S. Видимо стоит переделывать все использованные вектора под дин. массивы? Если переделываю, то придется использовать их и на месте `list` ?

Класс `polygon` для замены векторов:

```
class polygon
{
public:
    point *polygon_ = new point;
    size_t size_polygon;

    polygon(point polygon_[], size_t size_polygon) {
        this->polygon_ = polygon_;
        this->size_polygon = size_polygon;
    }
    polygon()
    {
        polygon P(polygon_, size_polygon);
    }
};
```

Comment: а что такое rtl? run-time library? Как по мне, то динамические массивы к ним ортогональны.

Comment: @ KoVadim, верно, run-time library. необходимо переделать под ее шаблоны. Не используя stl

Comment: Вам нужно детально уточнить у преподавателя, чем ему не нравятся векторы и что именно он имеет ввиду под rtl (может это какой то Rome Template Library).

Comment: @ KoVadim, вопрос дополнен